# What is meant with monotone and non-monotone traveling wave profiles?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Traveling wave profiles are solutions of some pde of the form $u=u(\xi)$ where $\xi=x-ct$.

Now I have read about *monotone* traveling waves and *non-monotone* traveling waves. What does this mean? For example I cannot imagine monotone pulses since pulses are traveling waves with $\lim_{\xi\to +\infty}u(\xi)=\lim_{\xi\to -\infty}u(\xi)$. How can this be monotone?

I have no idea what monotonicity means here.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the simplest example of what your asking about can be seen in the transport equation.  Consider the PDE
$$
\partial_t u(t,x) + c \partial_x u(t,x) =0  \text{ for }(t,x) \in \mathbb{R}^2\\
u(0,x) = f(x).
$$

If we propose a travelling wave ansatz of the form $u(t,x) = g(x-ct)$ then we find that 
$$
\partial_t u(t,x) = -c g'(x-ct) \text{ and } \partial_x u(t,x) = g'(x-ct). 
$$
Thus
$$
\partial_t u(t,x) + c \partial_x u(t,x) = -c g'(x-ct) + cg'(x-ct) = 0,
$$
and so we have have a solution to the PDE for any differential $g$.  Now we choose $g$ to match the data, namely we want 
$$
u(0,x) = f(x) \Leftrightarrow g(x) = g(x-c0) = f(x).
$$
This means that we solve the PDE by choosing $u(t,x) = f(x-ct)$.

Now, $f$ here is an arbitrary differentiable function, so in particular we can choose it to be monotone.  We could also choose "pulse-like" f instead.  However, if we impose the condition 
$$
\lim_{z \to \infty} f(z) = \lim_{z \to -\infty} f(z) 
$$
along with a monotonicity assumption, as you suggest, then necessarily $f$ is constant.

Of course, this is just for the transport equation.  Lots of other PDEs admit travelling wave solutions, but the ideas are similar.

Comment: Does this mean that pulses only can be monotone if they are constant?

Comment: Well, to be honest I'm not familiar with a formal definition of a "pulse," though the one you mention is consistent with what I would informally choose.  In any case, yes: if you define a pulse as in your post, then monotonicity and the pulse condition together require a constant.

Answer (score 1):

The monotonicity refers to the shape of the wave profile. Most travelling waves you encounter in applications are fronts, which look (for example) like the graph of $\text{tanh} (\xi)$. As the function describing the profile is (strictly) monotonic, the resulting travelling wave is called a monotone wave.

For a general system of PDEs allowing travelling wave solutions however, all kinds of wave profiles are possible. A very simple example is the Fisher-KPP equation $u_t = u_{xx} + u(1-u)$. A well known result (see for example [here](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/pdectb/fisher2.pdf)) is that for wave speeds $c < 2$, the wave profile has an oscillatory tail, and is therefore not monotonic.

Nb. You can use the mean value theorem to show that pulse solutions are monotonic if and only if they are trivial (constant).